# -I flag not working in make file

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile

I just wrote simple make file to compile any number of files. When I add -I flag to add include directory, its not working.

```
    CC=g++
    CFLAGS=-I./inc
    DEPS = add.h mul.h
    OBJ = main.o add.o mul.o 

    %.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

    main: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

following is the out put when I executed make. You can see -I./inc is missing

```
    ~/PGMS/testMakeFile > make
    g++    -c -o main.o main.cc
    main.cc:1:17: fatal error: add.h: No such file or directory
```

I already wasted long time to resolve this, can someone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule you've written to handle `.o` files is never called because it builds from `%.c` files instead of `%.cc` files. Thus, `make`'s implicit rule for `.cc` files is called with `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` C++ variables.

Change `CFLAGS=-I./inc` to `CXXFLAGS += -I./inc` and it should work.

---

All that said, the `-I` flag is a *preprocessor flag*, meaning you should actually be using the `CPPFLAGS` variable instead (and it will continue to work as expected since both `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` are implicitly used).

Your makefile can thus be simplified:

```make
OBJ := main.o add.o mul.o
DEP := add.h mul.h

CPPFLAGS := -Iinc

main: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ): $(DEP)
```

Comment: i was trying with different combination, even %.cc was not working. Let me try with CXXFLAGS. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a rule for .cc files (notice that your custom rule is to convert .c files into .o files).

Note that in gnu make (at least), the default c++ rule (i.e. for .cc files) uses the CXXFLAGS variable by default.  See [the GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html)

Comment: The `CPPFLAGS` variable is actually used for preprocessor flags. Use `CXXFLAGS` to provide flags for g++.

Comment: Gah.  You are correct of course, Chnossos, and (for accuracy's sake), I'll correct my answer.